# Can anyone help how to fix the screen resolution in ubuntu which i installed on my mac

Tags: display-resolution

I have installed Linux in mac but is is not working properly, I am getting vey small screen.   how to install ubuntu in mac book pro via virtual box

Comment: Did you replace OSx with Ubuntu previously, and are you now having resolution/graphical issues? Or did you install Ubuntu on a virtual box in Max and the display for the virtual box is very small?